# Find the peak of probability 30

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

If probability is P=1/3 and N=100, what is the probability you succeed 30 times? where does this P30 fall in the curve? I don't have mean or standard deviation to calculate the height of the point!

Comment: If you are asking for the mode of a binomial distribution, the formula is given in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this may be a textbook problem about the binomial distribution.
Here are some facts that will help you derive answers.

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 100,\, p = 1/3),$ then $\mu = E(X) = np = 100/3\,$
and $\sigma^2 = np(1-p).$ These formulas can be found in the Wikipedia article linked in my comment or in a basic probability book.

Also by the PDF (or PMF) formula for a binomial distribution you can find the probability
$$b(30;100,1/3)=P(X = 30) = {100 \choose 30}\left(\frac 1 3\right)^{30}\left(\frac 2 3\right)^{70} = 0.0673.$$
In R, the exact answer is

```
dbinom(30, 100, 1/3)
[1] 0.06728415
choose(100,30)*(1/3)^30*(2/3)^70
[1] 0.06728415
```

You can get a reasonably good approximation of this probability using the approximating normal distribution $X^\prime \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma),$ where
$\mu$ and $\sigma$ are as shown above. You will want $P(29.5 < X^\prime < 30.5).$

The plot below shows the values of the PDF of this binomial distribution with
the largest probabilities [vertical black bars]. In particular, the center of the small red circle shows $P(X=30).$ You can see that the mode agrees with the formula in Wikipedia. The density curve of the approximating normal distribution is shown in blue.

[image]

You can prove the result for the mode by simplifying the ratio
$\frac{b(k+1;100,1/3)}{b(k;100,1/3)}$ to see the values of $k$ for which
the ratio is less than 1 and the values for which the ratio is greater than 1.

Comment: I used to dbinom to find the probability of success 30 but my intention is to plot it over distribution. How can we assume the distribution to be normal? I don't have mean and sd values to decide if it's left skewed or right. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Look in a probability book to see guidelines for using a normal distribution to approximate binomial probabilities. This is an application of the Central Limit Theorem. // The figure shows that the normal approximation is good in this particular case. As illustrated above, one uses the binomial mean and SD to get the normal approximation. I showed you formulas for binomial $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the 2nd paragraph of my Answer; so you have $\mu$ and with a bit of computation you can get $\sigma$ also. // Your question is fragmentary, mentioning neither 'binomial' or 'normal'. Please clarify.

Comment: I think it should be binomial. there is no mention of the distribution though. What is b in your computation formula? I need to sketch the distribution and show where P(30) lies

Comment: Full meaning of problem might be revealed by its immediate context in the book. // My `b` is just a function name of the PDF (short for `binomial`). So $b(k;n,p) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, n.$ Frequently used notation, sorry if not in your book. [Also, fixed a typo that might have confused you.] // I think I have already shown a plot of the distribution; $P(X = 30)$ is the height of the black bar above `x=30` in my figure. [See the small red circle just now added to the plot.]